Compiler thinks numpy int_t is an invalid type
I found that when I tried to install the PyPI package bposd or ldpc I received the following error (on a mac):
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
  
  cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] char2numpy(char* char_array, int n)
                     ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  
  src/ldpc/c_util.pxd:11:19: Invalid type.

There is nothing wrong with the file and it compiles on another mac that I have without issue. Both are new Macbook Pros. So I tried a simple test cython program like
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def process_array(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] array):
cdef int sum_values = 0
cdef int i

for i in range(array.shape[0]):
    sum_values += array[i]

return sum_values

This also gave me an error on the np.int_t. This was done on a fresh python venv environment with only numpy and cython installed. Any ideas of where the problem might be?

I think Numpy2 may have dropped the int_t type. You probably need to use either int32_t or int64_t depending on your preference

@DavidW I don't think that is the issue. int_t is defined in numpy/init.pxd :
ctypedef npy_long       int_t

@mgns If you're looking at the file within Cython that's no longer maintained and will be removed fairly soon. Cython will use the .pxd files distributed by Numpy itself in preference.

@vand I tried running your example and it works fine for me. If I import numpy as pynp (to distinguish from the cimport, I recommend always doing this, alternatively the cimport as cnp) and then change np.int_t to pynp.int_t, I get your error. This makes sense because int_t is not defined in the python import, only in the c import. So I would guess in your setting the wrong numpy import is used, for whatever reason. Try changing only the first line to "import numpy as pynp"?

@DavidW no I meant the /init.pxd file in numpy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/init.pxd
